# Get Total numbers of each element in Array of MongoDB Object

Tags: arrays, mongodb, loops, mongoose, analytics

I have a set of objects in a MongoDB. The object includes an array of types. Now I am connecting to the DB with Mongoose and would like to now the number of objects for each Type.

For example my objects look like

```
{
"name": "abc",
"tags": ["a","b","c"]
}
```

Now I would like to get the total number of Objects which for example have the Tag "a"

I am connecting to the MongoDB with a NodeJS Backend using Mongoose

Thanks for your Ideas on how to query this efficiently.

**Addition**:
In the case where I don't know what kind of different tags are existing in the different objects and I would like to get an overview of all tags, how do I need to query on this one? For better understanding I give an example. 
Two objects in the database:

```
{
"name": "abc",
"tags": ["a","b","c"]
},
{
"name": "abc",
"tags": ["a","b"]
}
```

the function/query should give a response of something like this:

```
{
"a": 2,
"b": 2,
"c": 1
}
```

Comment: `Model.find({ tags: "a" })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$tags" },
    {$group: {
        _id: "$tags",  
        count: {$sum : 1}  
    }},

]);
```

this will give output like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "c",
    "count" : 2
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "b",
    "count" : 3
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "a",
    "count" : 2
}
```

Comment: OP is interested in only counts not the returned objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In my case I would like to know the count for every Tag without knowing which tags are existing. So I also have to query for all the different tags in every object. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I mean that I don't now which tags are used. One object uses tags "a" and "b" and one uses "c". I would then like to get a response of one "a" one "b" and one "c" usage.

Answer (score 0):

Use `count` which is a collection method. It returns the count only instead of all documents. If You need the documents , replace `count` with `find`

```
collection.count({tags:"a"})
```